# Get boolean return value of forEach

Tags: javascript

I have a forEach loop where it has a find function inside of it. I'd like to get a boolean value after the forEach is executed only if all the find functions being looped return true. How can this be done?

```js
const items = ['apple','orange','banana'];
items.forEach((item)=>{
const value = !!items?.find((element)=>element==='apple')
console.log(value) // true, false, false -> return of forEach should be false
})
```

```js
const items = ['apple','apple','apple'];
items.forEach((item)=>{
const value = !!items?.find((element)=>element==='apple')
console.log(value) // true, true, true -> return of forEach should be true
})
```

Something along the lines of

```js
isAllTruthy = items.forEach((item)=>{
return !!items?.find((element)=>element==='apple')

})
```

This gives the return value undefined, how do I approach this

Comment: You can use `.every` for this. Check it out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: btw, what result do you expect? a single boolean or an array of boolean values?

Comment: @NinaScholz See the comments in the code for the expected outcome. Also "_I'd like to get a boolean value after the forEach is executed only if all the find functions being looped return true._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the result of the checks. This allowes to return a value for each item of the array.

```js
const
    items = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'],
    result = items.map(s => s === 'apple');

console.log(result);
```

If you like to get a single boolean value, you could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
console.log(['apple', 'orange', 'banana'].every(s => s === 'apple'));
console.log(['apple', 'apple', 'apple'].every(s => s === 'apple'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.every` like this:

```js
const items = ["apple", "orange", "banana"];
let value = items.every((item) => item === "apple");
console.log(value); // false

const items2 = ["apple", "apple", "apple"];
value = items2.every((item) => item === "apple");
console.log(value); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only map array method for get return boolean value

```js
const items = ['apple','orange','banana'];

console.log(items.map((e)=> e === 'apple'))
```

Answer (score 0):

forEach returns undefined regardless of your return statement [array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

So if you need a return value you can use, array.map() or a for loop or any other method enables you to return custom value